# Function classes with high Rademacher complexity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability, learning-theory

My question is two fold,

- Is there any general understanding of what makes a function class have high Rademacher complexity? (Sudakov minoration would say that one sufficient condition for a class of functions to have a high Rademacher complexity is if it has high packing number in the corresponding pseudo-metric. So one can also ask as to if we know of properties of a function class which will lead it to have a large packing number.)
- A possibly commonly occurring situation is that over some domain X, we explicitly know of a function $g^* : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we look at the $\epsilon-$ball around $g^*$ inside some larger function space $F$. Is there anything known about conditions when is such an epsilon ball around a specific function of high Rademacher complexity?

Comment: Why is this getting a negative vote!? Is anything wrong with the question?

Comment: This is far from a full characterization, but hopefully an illustrative example. The class of all Lipschitz functions on a metric space with finite diameter and doubling dimension will have a large Rademacher complexity if the doubling dimension is large.

Comment: Thanks! And where can I read up this proof?

Comment: A moment's reflection on the upper bounds established here shows that they are in fact tight: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6867374